# How exactly does the mergeMap operator work and in which cases is it used?

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs, mergemap

Before coming here I have read the official documentation of Rxjs and some other pages but I am still not clear. What I understood is this:

It is used to "join" 2 observables and thus obtain a single observable as a result, I also saw that it is used to "flatten" an observable (I am also not very clear).

Now ... I have days trying to program a user registry using Angular and Node.js with Express and I found a little tutorial which I decided to use and it has this code:

```js
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

 constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  let accessToken = "", refreshToken = ""

  const tokens = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("tokens"))
  if (tokens) {
   accessToken = tokens.accessToken
   refreshToken = tokens.refreshToken
  }

  let clonHttp: HttpRequest<any> 
  clonHttp = tokens ? req.clone({ headers: req.headers.append("Authorization", `Bearer ${accessToken}`) }) : req
  
  let auth = this.injector.get(AuthenticationService);

  return next.handle(clonHttp)
   .pipe(
    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
     if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.log("error event")
     } else if (error.status == 401) {
      return auth.getNewAccessToken(refreshToken)
       .pipe(
        retry(3),
        mergeMap(
         (response: any) => {
          tokens.accessToken = response.accessToken
          sessionStorage.setItem("tokens", JSON.stringify(tokens))

          clonHttp = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.append("Authorization", `Bearer ${response.accessToken}`) })
          return next.handle(clonHttp)
         }
        )
       )
     } else if (error.status == 409) {
      return throwError("User not logged")
     } else {
      if (error.error && error.error.message) {
       return throwError(error.error.message)
      } else {
       return throwError("Check your connection")
      }
     }
    })
   )
 }

}
```

If you see, when you use the MergeMap operator they only pass you the answer (a single observable), or at least that's what I can see. What I'm trying to say is that I don't see that they are using it with 2 observables or to mix 2 observables, which is what I have read in their official documentation, in fact, in the examples they show they always use it with 2 observables.

Honestly it has been too difficult for me to understand this operator, if someone could help me understand it in a simple way, I would be extremely grateful, in addition to understanding its use in that code that I show earlier. Greetings in advance. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`mergeMap`, like many other so-called higher order mapping operators, maintains **one or multiple** inner observables.

An **inner observable** is created with the **outer value** and the **provided function**. The **outer value** essentially is just the value received from its source. For example:

```js
of(1, 2, 3).pipe(
  mergeMap((outerValue, index) => /* ... return an observable ... */)
).subscribe(); // `outerValue`: 1, 2, 3 (separately)
```

When an outer value comes in, a **new inner observable** will be created. I think the best way to understand this is to have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/mergeMap.ts#L122-L141):

```js
// `value` - the `outerValue`
protected _next(value: T): void {
  if (this.active < this.concurrent) {
    this._tryNext(value);
  } else {
    this.buffer.push(value);
  }
}

protected _tryNext(value: T) {
  let result: ObservableInput<R>;
  const index = this.index++;
  try {
    // Create the inner observable based on the `outerValue` and the provided function (`this.project`)
    // `mergeMap(project)`
    result = this.project(value, index);
  } catch (err) {
    this.destination.error(err);
    return;
  }
  this.active++;
  // Subscribe to the inner observable
  this._innerSub(result, value, index);
}
```

Please disregard for now `concurrent` and `buffer`, we'll have a look at them a bit later.

Now, what happens when an inner observable emits ? Before going any further, it's worth mentioning that, although it's obvious, an **inner observable** **requires** an **inner subscriber**. We can see this in the `_innerSub` method from above:

```js
private _innerSub(ish: ObservableInput<R>, value: T, index: number): void {
  const innerSubscriber = new InnerSubscriber(this, value, index);
  const destination = this.destination as Subscription;
  destination.add(innerSubscriber);
  // This is where the subscription takes place
  subscribeToResult<T, R>(this, ish, undefined, undefined, innerSubscriber);
}
```

When an inner observable emits, the [`notifyNext` method](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/mergeMap.ts#L158-L162) will be called:

```js
notifyNext(outerValue: T, innerValue: R,
            outerIndex: number, innerIndex: number,
            innerSub: InnerSubscriber<T, R>): void {
  this.destination.next(innerValue);
}
```

Where destination points to the next subscriber in the chain. For example, it can be this:

```js
of(1)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(/* ... */)
  )
  .subscribe({} /* <- this is the `destination` for `mergeMap` */)
```

This will be explained in more detail in **What about the *next subscriber in the chain*** below.

So, what does it mean to `to mix 2 observables` ?

Let's see this example:

```js
of(2, 3, 1)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(outerValue => timer(outerValue).pipe(mapTo(outerValue)))
  )
  .subscribe(console.log)
  /* 1 \n 2 \n 3 */
```

When `2` arrives, `mergeMap` will subscribe to an inner observable that will emit in `200`ms. This is an asynchronous action, but notice that the outer values(2, 3, 1) arrive synchronously. Next, `3` arrives and will create an inner obs. that will emit in `300`ms. Since the current script has not finished executing yet, the callback queue is not yet considered. Now `1` arrives, and will create an inner obs. that will emit in `100` ms.

`mergeMap` has now 3 inner observables and will pass along the **inner value** of whichever inner observable emits.
As expected, we get `1`, `2`, `3`.

So that's what `mergeMap` does. *Mixing observables* can be thought of this way: if an outer value comes and an inner observable has already been created, then `mergeMap` simply says: "no problem, I'll just create a new inner obs. and subscribe to it".

#### What about `concurrent` and `buffer`

`mergeMap` can be given a second argument, `concurrent` which indicates how many inner observables should handle at the same time. These number of active inner observables is tracked with the `active` property.

As seen in `_next` method, if `active >= concurrent`, the `outerValues` will be added to a `buffer`, which is a queue(`FIFO`).

Then, when one active inner observable **completes**, `mergeMap` will take the oldest value from the value and will create an inner observable out of it, using the provided function:

```js
// Called when an inner observable completes
notifyComplete(innerSub: Subscription): void {
  const buffer = this.buffer;
  this.remove(innerSub);
  this.active--;
  if (buffer.length > 0) {
    this._next(buffer.shift()!); // Create a new inner obs. with the oldest buffered value
  } else if (this.active === 0 && this.hasCompleted) {
    this.destination.complete();
  }
}
```

With this in mind, `concatMap(project)` is just `mergeMap(project, 1)`.

So, if you have:

```js
of(2, 3, 1)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(outerValue => timer(outerValue * 100).pipe(mapTo(outerValue)), 1)
  )
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

this will be logged:

`2 \n 3 \n 1`.

#### What about the *next subscriber in the chain*

Operators are **functions** that **return** another **function** which accepts an **observable** as their **only parameter** and **return** another **observable**.
When a stream is being subscribed to, each observable returned by an operator will have its **own subscriber**.

All these subscribers can be seen as a linked list. For example:

```js
// S{n} -> Subscriber `n`, where `n` depends on the order in which the subscribers are created

of(/* ... */)
  .pipe(
    operatorA(), // S{4}
    operatorB(), // S{3}
    operatorC(), // S{2}
  ).subscribe({ /* ... */ }) // S{1}; the observer is converted into a `Subscriber`
```

`S{n}` is the parent(**destination**) of `S{n+1}`, meaning that `S{1}` is the destination of `S{2}`, `S{2}` is the destination of `S{3}` and so forth.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mergemap-explained?file=index.ts)

---

### Unexpected results

Compare these:

```js
of(2, 1, 0)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(v => timer(v * 100).pipe(mapTo(v)))
  ).subscribe(console.log)
// 0 1 2
```

```js
of(2, 1, 0)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(v => timer(v).pipe(mapTo(v)))
  ).subscribe(console.log)
// 1 0 2
```

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals):

> The specified amount of time (or the delay) is not the guaranteed time to execution, but rather the minimum time to execution. The callbacks you pass to these functions cannot run until the stack on the main thread is empty.
>
> As a consequence, code like setTimeout(fn, 0) will execute as soon as the stack is empty, not immediately. If you execute code like setTimeout(fn, 0) but then immediately after run a loop that counts from 1 to 10 billion, your callback will be executed after a few seconds.

[This section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified) by MDN should clarify things as well.

I'd say this is environment-specific, rather than RxJs-specific.

In the second snippet, the delays are consecutive so that's why you're getting *unexpected results*. If you increase the delays just a bit, like: `timer(v * 2)`, you should get the expected behavior.

Comment: Hi friend, thanks for replying. I was reviewing your answer and I was testing the code to try to understand the concept better and I tried modifying this like this: of (2, 1, 0), the result is this: 1, 0, 2 in that order, I don't understand why it happens that shouldn't be 0, 1, 2?

Answer (score 0):

So merge map is mainly used to resolve multiple inner observables concurrently and when all inner observables are resolved outer observable will resolve. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. precisely that is my biggest doubt. In the code that I put only one observable (response) is passed to it, and as I understand it is to solve more than one observable (or it must be), so I do not understand very well why they use it that way in that code.

Comment: So basically what I understand from your code is you are using the angular's HTTP interceptor concept and then you are writing your own logic. So for implementing http interceptor you will have to return an observable via next.handle before that you need some observables to resolve concurrently including retry concept of rxjs.

Comment: Rxjs documentations were nightmares for me as well. Please refer some other websites or tutorials. It is not easy but very interesting concept to learn.

Comment: I am not clear. There could have been used the operator "tap" for example, instead of the operator merMap? Because I see that what they do is just use the response data (without modifying it).

Comment: No tap won't solve your problem because tap won't resolve inner observable it will just tap onto some stream but won't resolve inner stream. So you got to be clear about what you are doing.

Comment: mmm ... well, I'm still not clear, I have to keep looking and looking to see if I can understand someday. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have to to read a list of `id`s from some async source, being it a remote service, a DB, a file on your file system.

Imagine that you have to launch an async query for each `id` to get the details.

Imagine you have to collect all the details for each `id` and do something else.

You end up having an initial Obsersable emitting a list and then a bunch of of Observables generated by that list. This is were you would use `mergeMap`.

The code would look like this

```
mySourceObs = getIdListFromSomewhere();

myStream = mySourceObs.pipe(
   // after you get the list of the ids from your service, you generate a new strem
   // which emits all the values of the list via from operator
   concatMap(listOfIds => from(listOfIds)),
   // for each id you get the details
   mergeMap(id => getDetails(id),
)
```

If you subscribe to `myStream` you get a stream of details data, one for every `id` of the original list. The code would be simply

```
myStream.subscribe(
  detail => {
    // do what you have to do with the details of an id
  }
)
```

**MORE ON THE CODE REFERENCED IN THE QUESTION**

My understanding of piece of code using `mergeMap` is the following:

1. you fetch a new token with `auth.getNewAccessToken`
2. If something goes wrong you retry 3 times
3. When you receive a fresh token, you do some stuff and then you clone something with `next.handle(clonHttp)`

Key point is that both `auth.getNewAccessToken` and `next.handle(clonHttp)` are async calls returning an Observable.

In this case you want to make sure that FIRST you get the response from `auth.getNewAccessToken` and ONLY THEN you call `next.handle(clonHttp)`.

In this case the best way to code such logic is using `concatMap` which ensures that the second Observable is concatenated to the successful completion of the first one.

`mergeMap` and `switchMap` can also work in this scenario since `auth.getNewAccessToken` emits only ONCE and then completes, but the right semantic is given by `concatMap` (which by the way is the same as `mergeMap` with concurrency set to 1, but this is another story).

Comment: and in the code that I put in my question, what function would mergeMap be doing? could it have been done with the "tap" operator for example? is that I don't understand why they used MergeMap if only the response is passing it.